# Deprecated function CRM_Core_Config::defaultContactCountry error

Tags: error, tags, configandlog

In the ConfigandLog directory, this error is produced every minute:

```
[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_Config::defaultContactCountry, use CRM_Core_BAO_Country::defaultContactCountry.
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

What configuration do I have wrong that is making this occur?

On Civi 5.24.4 / Wordpress 5.4.1. Multisite.

Comment: My guess would be it's coming from an extension. Try `grep -r defaultContactCountry your_extensions_folder` to see what comes up.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/v7skYeWP

Comment: Just noticed it's already patched in master. Have updated answer.

Comment: We were on 1.0. Apparently the ext does not give an upgrade notice. Now running into enabling issue https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.normalize/issues/11#issuecomment-634971434. Should I care that the enabling didn't go smoothly but still says enabled?

Comment: That seems like a separate error but upgrading just to 1.1 won't help with the original problem since the patch is only in master (latest dev). They might be open to releasing a new version 1.2 since it's been a while since the last release. For this second error, if it only comes up during enabling then it's probably because of changes in which hooks run during enabling - hook_civicrm_config probably isn't called anymore. So if you don't see the error during regular use it's probably ok.

Comment: Should I try master or just do the patch?

Comment: Me personally I would probably just do the patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like cividesk.normalize based on the pastebin.

Actually looks like it's already patched in master: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.normalize/commit/221562b8bf4fb56fe677eaaf9122d3af5c3cce74